# Facebook Login API with JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I want to have FB login on my site but unable to do it, please help.

I just have login button with JavaScript SDK on this page [fb-login page](https://www.gorkhalisewa.com/ihf/login-1.php). After login it doesnot go anywhere.

I have added this link `https://www.gorkhalisewa.com/ihf/` on **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** section on FB App. It does not go anywhere..

Please help! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what do you mean with "it does not go anywhere"? there is no code that redirects after login. you just do some console.log entries.

Comment: Thanks for responding, as per facebook sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/ at #1 we just need to add redirect URL. I added valid uri but it does not go there after login.

Comment: your test page does not work anymore. if you post a link on stackoverflow, make sure it stays valid in the future. better post the relevant code instead.

Comment: anyway, the docs state that you need to add a redirect url in the settings, but afaik you are using FB.login - so it is up to you what to do after login, it will not just magically redirect.